# error al instalar Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll

Tags: c#, dll

Estoy utilizando el paquete para Visual Studio de `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll Version 15.0.0.0`, pero al compilar el proyecto me da el siguiente error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'No se pudo recuperar el generador de clases COM para el componente con CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} debido al siguiente error: 80040154 Clase no registrada (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).'
```

Según he investigado dicen que debo registrar primero la dll, pero al intentar hacerlo mediante el comando:

```
Regsvr32.exe  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll"
```

Me da el error de:

```
Se cargó el modulo "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll", pero no se encontró el punto de entrada DllRegisterServer.
```

> Asegúrese de que "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll" es un archivo DLL u OCX válido e inténtelo de nuevo.

¿Qué es lo que puedo hacer?